# What does ASP.NET MVC internally use?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, session-state

What does aspnet mvc internally use (for routing)?

Application, Session, Viewstate, Cookies, Cross Page Data, Context.Items, Profiles???????

I mean how can it maintain states w/o using any of the above techniques?

Comment: which states are you talking about, are you talking of route info??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC routing uses none of the above. It maintains no state. Internally it uses a static dictionary to store the route definition but that's an implementation detail that you should not depend on for any reason as it might change in future versions.

Comment: This actually helped me a bunch, but my question was very different. I'm trying to learn MVC, but I'm a much more traditional programmer only recently exposed to web stuff. In doing a tutorial, the PageData looked a bit like ViewState or cookies and your answer cleared up how it's different. Thanks!